# MySQL Query causing High CPU spike on Magento Store

Tags: mysql, database, magento, cpu

My Magento store has suddenly had a large spike in CPU usage because of the following MySQL query consistently running:

```
SELECT 
    `d`.`entity_id` 
FROM 
    `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `d`
LEFT JOIN 
    `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `c` ON c.attribute_id = '42' AND     
    c.store_id = '1' AND 
    c.entity_id = d.entity_id 
WHERE 
    (d.attribute_id = '42') AND 
    (d.store_id = '0') AND 
    (d.entity_id IN 
    (SELECT 
        `e`.`entity_id` 
    FROM 
        `catalog_category_entity` AS `e` 
    WHERE 
        (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '3') AND 
        (`e`.`entity_id` IN
        ('4', '31', '71', '72', '450',
        // this continues to contain around 2000+ id's...
```

I have no idea where this is coming from or what is causing this? Can anyone help shed some light on explaining what this is attempting and if there is anything to suggest what is causing it?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know structure of Magento DB but I think you should add index to `entity_id`

Comment: This seems like a very complex case. I will need more details in order to help you, is it happening in the home? category view? What is the result of execute in mysql command line "show fullprocess list;"